# Mount HFS+ for free (even readonly) for more than 10 days on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems

I'd love to mount (even read-only) an external HFS+ filesystem for Windows for more than 10 days:

MacDrive has 5 days trial and Paragon HFS+ has a 10 days trial.

I tried [jhfsplus](https://sf.net/p/jhfsplus/files) but it does not detect my HFS+ partition on Windows 10.

Is there a free tool or driver that can do that on Windows?